# How to name Morning and Evening if the numbers are repeated twice in Excel

Tags: excel

I have dates with Numbers(ColumA) in Excel, I want to create a new column where I need to capture "Morning" and "evening"(ColumnB) depends on the numbers. Maybe the column A can be negative value
If the same numbers are repeated twice, the first entry should be Morning, and the second entry should be Evening

How to do it in Excel.

**CurrentOutput**

```
ColumnA ColumnB
87      
87
-89
-89
90
90
91
90
```

**Expected output**:

```
ColumnA ColumnB
87      Morning
87      Evening
-89      Morning
-89      Evening
90      Morning
90      Evening
91
90
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a clunky formula that should do what you want.

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$9, $A2)>=2,IFERROR(CHOOSE(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2),"Morning","Evening"),""),"")
```